# Trying to install java2python and keep getting error message below:

Tags: java, python

Ive tried to download using:

```
pip3 install java2python
pip install java2python
brew install java2python
```

I've tried using all of those methods above but still get the same output:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement antlr_python_runtime==3.1.3 (from java2python) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for antlr_python_runtime==3.1.3 (from java2python)
```

How would I solve this?

Comment: What version of python are you using? The package says it required 2.7 https://pypi.org/project/java2python/

Comment: This software is a bit prehistoric.  It looks like the last real update was 7+ years ago and doesn't support Python 3.  How much code do you convert from Java to Python?

Comment: @chrisbyte and stdunbar I believe both of your comments are accurate. I was running this on python 3. Will try again with python 2. Other than that, would any of you know how to translate java to python using some sort of program?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following commands :

```sh
pip install http://antlr3.org/download/Python/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3.tar.gz
pip install https://github.com/downloads/natural/java2python/java2python-0.5.1.tar.gz
```

I believe this works perfectly fine with `python 2.7`